# How can I get an element included in a HTML span tag using Selenium in Python?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I'm new here and I'm trying to scrap results from a triathlon.
The problem is that I'm not able to get the information that I want.
The website URL is: https://www.acn-timing.com/?lng=FR#/events/2141423449174261/ctx/20230725_alpehuez/generic/198021_2/home/TRI2

Here's the HTML code that interests me:

```
<td class="text-bold">
    <span>VINUELA GONZALEZ Kevin Tarek</span>
```

Here's my code:

```
# Set list of elements
names = []

# Find all names
name_elements = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "text-bold")
for name in name_elements:
    information = name.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "span").text
    names.append(information)
```

When I run my python file I get this error:
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"tag name","selector":"span"}

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Selenium acts in real time.  If this is a dynamic web site, you need to make sure that the elements actually exist before you go looking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Selenium is the last effort in scraping because it loads the entire browser + webdrivers so it is a resource hog and slow. The page also have paging with adds more complexity if you like the entire result list.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import logging,time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--headless=new")
wd = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
t0 = time.time()
url = "https://www.acn-timing.com/?lng=FR#/events/2141423449174261/ctx/20230725_alpehuez/generic/198021_2/home/TRI2"
wd.get(url)
WebDriverWait(wd, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//tbody[@class='table-data']")))
table = wd.find_element(By.XPATH, "//tbody[@class='table-data']")
rows = table.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//tr[@class='last-record-line']")
for i,row in enumerate(rows):
    out = []
    cols = row.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "td")
    for c in cols:    
        out.append(c.text)
    print(f"{i:03d}:{out}")
print(f"scraping one page took:{time.time()-t0:.2f}sec")
```

```
000:['1.', '14', 'VINUELA GONZALEZ Kevin Tarek', '', '3', '17:25', '1:29', '1', '1:08:58', '1', '55', '4', '23:41', 'Finish', '1:52:29', '1/28', 'ELM', '', '']
001:['2.', '18', 'LEJEUNE Emmanuel', '', '15', '19:18', '1:30', '5', '1:12:08', '3', '55', '5', '23:52', 'Finish', '1:57:46', '2/28', 'ELM', '', '']
:
094:['100.', '913', 'BORTENLANGER Sébastien', '', '236', '26:09', '2:08', '113', '1:28:35', '102', '1:09', '128', '29:49', 'Finish', '2:27:52', '9/221', 'M30-34', '', '']
scraping one page took:21.26sec
```

Comment: Perfect! Indeed I would at the end get all data but just asked with names to understand where I was wrong but you bring me everything! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Since I can see that these results are stored within table tag, so you can use following tag for record:

```
name_records = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='main']//tr/td[3]/span")
```

and for getting names within one page, you can use following logic:

```
name_record_xpath = "//*[@id='main']//tr/td[3]/span"
record_name = "//*[@id='main']//tr[13]/td[3]/span"

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, name_record_xpath)))
name_records = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, name_record_xpath)
first_name_record = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, record_name)
actions.move_to_element(first_name_record).perform()


names = []
for i in name_records:
    names.append(i.text)
print(names)
```

and here is the output for that:

```
['VINUELA GONZALEZ Kevin Tarek', 'LEJEUNE Emmanuel', 'DUPUIS Igor', 'NAVARRO Thomas', 'LEBOIS Paul', 'PETRALIA Jan', 'LAWSON Théotime', 'MANTULET Gabin', 'VOTTIER Antoine', 'PORAS Maxime', 'HEEMERYCK Sander', 'VAN HEMEL Tim', 'TEXEREAU Théo', 'RIVRON Maxime', 'MATTER Tanguy', 'SATTLER Finn', 'DEWEZ Maxime', 'FERANDEAU Julien', 'MARCEAU Olivier', 'FUCHO Diego', 'KARDES Alexis', 'AESCHLIMANN Pierre', 'DELAHAYE Thibaut', 'BAELDE Ibe', 'GOURET Maël', 'DA MOTA Julien', 'DOMANICO Baptiste', 'LERNO Tom', 'MERLE Audrey', 'BOULAY Jérémy', 'BOURSEAUX Yannick', 'ALLICHON Yann', 'DE JAEGHER Arthur', 'CHOUVELON Corentin', 'BROUTE Roméo', 'GALLEGO Pierre-Emmanuel', 'NOPPE Arthur', 'BISSARDON Mael', 'LOPEZ SANTAMARIA Sergio', 'LEVILLAIN Hugo', 'CASTEL Maxence', 'CORNELISSE Eva', 'DAL Lucas', 'GUEUDRE Thomas', 'DE COUVREUR François', 'DEVLIEGHER Arne', 'MAGANA Antoine', 'LE PALUD François', 'WOOD Thomas', 'BROCHET Maxime', 'VAN BRUMMELEN Clément', 'BAGUET Charles', 'OSORO GUTIERREZ Txomin', 'DIEUMEGARD Robin', 'GOMEZ CIRUJANO Jose Manuel', 'HEITZ Louis', 'MERLE Célia', 'MICHEL Luc', 'CORNET Fiona', 'AMEY Thibaut', 'BUA Laurent', 'DUPONT Jeanne', 'BALAGNA Ghislain', 'MARTINET Guillaume', 'ROCCHIA Christophe', 'KAUFFMANT Tristan', 'KALISVAART Pim', 'VAN ASSCHE Bas', 'DI GIUSEPPE Alexandre', 'ALVAREZ PALACIOS Julio', 'COUTAND Benjamin', 'CHRETIEN Edouard', 'CORNET Guillaume', 'AUSSAL Xavier', 'JONGMAN Tim', 'AMEY Xavier', 'BARIL Alexandre', 'LEAU Matthis', 'WARD Alan', 'BELE Theo', 'BAUDIER Pierrick', 'TEAM IDO', 'CHOQUEREAU Olivier', 'GRECO Thomas', 'WAUGH Joe', 'CASTEL Alexandre', 'BIZEL Louis', 'SANZ Ramon', 'BRUN Benjamin', 'LAFFONT Grégory', 'VIDAL Pierrick', 'CHEMINAUD Enzo', 'MONJO François', 'SCHWELLNUS Cyrille', 'FAUCON Frederic', 'ANDOUARD Gaël', 'MENGUY Baptiste', 'JOERI Nysen', 'COCUSSE Dominique', 'BORTENLANGER Sébastien']
```